# Copying content of one spreadsheet into another

Tags: excel, vba, copy, spreadsheet

I have 2 different excel files, stored in C:\Test:

1. Book1.xlsx, with Sheet1 (data in the Sheet1 is changing, not constant data-range, but always starts from A1 cell)
2. Book2.xlsm, with Sheet2 (empty)

Every time after opening Book2, I need data from Sheet1 of Book1 to be automatically copied into Sheet2 of Book2.

Update:
I tried the following vba code (researched online from Excel Forum)

```
     Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     Application.EnableEvents = False
     Dim swb As Workbook, Lr As Long, LC As Long, sws As Worksheet
     Dim dCell As Range, srg As Range, dwb As Workbook, dws As Worksheet
     Set swb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\AAA\Book1.xlsx")
     Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     Lr = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     LC = sws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     Set srg = sws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Lr, LC))
     Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
     Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
     Set dCell = dws.Range("A1")
     srg.Copy dCell
     swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
     dwb.Save
     Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

But, the problem with this - that if I delete a few records after the 1st one from Sheet1 of Book1, then - these deleted records still appear in the Sheet2 of Book2!

I am not great in vba, it's just a part of my whole project
Sorry for these questions

Update 2:

When I have the following in Sheet1, Book1:

[image]

Then, after opening Sheet2, Book2, I see (which is correct, what I expected):

[image]

But, if I'll delete records in Sheet1, Book1 (starting from the 2nd):

[image]

Then, after opening Sheet2, Book2 I will still see those deleted from Book2 records (while I expect them to be gone):

[image]

Comment: @braX I just edited my main question - added an update to it (what I've researched and the problem associated with it)

Comment: Do you mean that there are empty rows in the middle of the 'table'? Could you post a screenshot where it is obvious what is happening with the data?

Comment: @VBasic2008 No, there is no empty rows in the middle of the sheet...
Let me try to screenshot of what's happening

Comment: @VBasic2008 Ok, just updated my problem with the screenshots!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the destination sheet has more data than the source sheet, you will need to clear it before you copy over the data. You could do it with the Range-method `ClearContents`:

```
Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
dws.Usedrange.ClearContents
Set dCell = dws.Range("A1")
srg.Copy dCell
```

As it seems that you are copying the data of the whole sheet, an alternative could be to remove the sheet in `ThisWorkbook` and copy the sheet itself:

```
' Delete Sheet2 (if present)
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

' Copy Sheet from sourceWorkbook
sws.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2" ' Copied sheet gets the active sheet automatically.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clear Range Below Copied Data

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, LR As Long, LC As Long
    Dim dwb As Workbook, dws As Worksheet, dCell As Range

    Set swb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\AAA\Book1.xlsx")
    Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LR = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = sws.Cells(1, sws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set srg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(1, 1), sws.Cells(LR, LC))

    Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set dCell = dws.Range("A1")

    srg.Copy dCell
    
    With dCell.Resize(, srg.Columns.Count)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - srg.Rows.Count + 1) _
            .Offset(srg.Rows.Count).Clear
    End With
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    dwb.Save

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you as well  I'll check it out!